# Open InfoWindow using KeyDown/KeyPress

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm just wondering if there is a way to open Google Map InfoWindow by keyboard. So far, I can only make it open by click.

I found the following: http://www.visionaustralia.org/digital-access-googlemap
but it only handles the controls and navigation.

```
$(function(){
    //use mapselector="div" if you don't know the map id
    var mapSelector = "#map_canvas div";
    var attemptInterval = 2;
    var maxAttempts = 18;
    var mA = 0;
    var notYet = true;
    var titles = {"pan up":1,"pan down":1,"pan right":1,"pan left":1, "zoom in":1,"zoom out":1,"show street map":1,"show satellite imagery":1};

    function addKey(){
        mA++;
        if(mA > maxAttempts){return;}
        $(mapSelector).each(function(index){

        var title = this.getAttribute("title")
        if(title) title=title.toLowerCase().trim();
        if(title in titles){
            jqel = $(this);
            titles[title] = jqel;
            jqel.attr("tabindex","0");
            jqel.attr("role","button");
            jqel.keydown(function(ev){
                if(ev.which==13) {
                    $(this).trigger("click")
                }else if(ev.which==40) {
                    titles["pan down"].trigger("click");
                }else if(ev.which==38) {
                    titles["pan up"].trigger("click");
                }else if(ev.which==37) {
                    titles["pan left"].trigger("click");
                }else if(ev.which==39) {
                    titles["pan right"].trigger("click");
                }else if(ev.which==61 || ev.which == 187) {
                    titles["zoom in"].trigger("click");
                }else if(ev.which==173 || ev.which == 189) {
                    titles["zoom out"].trigger("click");
                }else{
                    return
                }
                ev.preventDefault();
            });

            (function(){
                var mo = false;
                var bo = jqel.css("border");
                var ma = jqel.css("margin");
                var bc = jqel.css("background-color");
                var op = jqel.css("opacity");

                jqel.mouseover(function(){mo=true;});
                jqel.mouseout(function(){mo=false;});
                jqel.focus(function(){
                    if(mo)return;
                    $(this).css({"border":"2px solid blue","margin":"-2px","background-color":"transparent","opacity":"1"});
                });
                jqel.blur(function(){$(this).css({"border":bo,"margin":ma,"background-color":bc,"opacity":op});});
                notYet = false;
            })();
        }
    });
    if(notYet){setTimeout(addKey,attemptInterval*1000);}
}
addKey();
```

});

It works by getting the title of the controls so I tried to add a title to the marker and adding it to the titles array but it doesn't work.

I'm quite new with Google Maps API and JavaScript, any suggestions on where to get started? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on my Google Maps API knowledge, but if I remember correctly, the API does indeed give a way to attach a listener to your marker. However, it does not work for keypress events, as you have noticed. For completeness, the basic syntax is this:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

The `addListener` function accepts three parameters:

- The item on which to attach the event (the marker in this case)
- The type of event to listen for
- The lamba or function to execute when the event occurs (opening an infoWindow)

The important bit here is the second parameter, the event for which to listen. These are *not* actual DOM events, but Google's own abstracted events (for better cross-browser support) and thus only a [select amount](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) is available - there is no keypress event.

JavaScript, on the other hand, does recognize several key events. I'm cowardly assuming you have jQuery available (from your posted example code), so you could exploit jQuery's `keypress` function to capture, well, a key press and opening an infoWindow with that:

```js
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 102:
            // lowercase f
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            break;
    }
});
```

This should open your defined infoWindow on your defined marker position. Note that this example does only contain code to open *one* infoWindow for *one* marker. But it should give you a general idea.

See [the following Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ax5c9n0/) I made for a very rough and simple example, using the 'f' key to open your infoWindow (after clicking in the "result" frame).